# How to split using multi-char separator with pipe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to split a string column of a dataframe in spark based on a delimiter ":|:|:"

```
Input:
TEST:|:|:51:|:|:PHT054008056
```

Test code:

```
dataframe1
.withColumn("splitColumn", split(col("testcolumn"), ":|:|:"))
```

Result:

```
+------------------------------+
|splitColumn                   |
+------------------------------+
|[TEST, |, |, 51, |, |, P]     |   
+------------------------------+
```

Test code:

```
dataframe1
.withColumn("part1", split(col("testcolumn"), ":|:|:").getItem(0))
.withColumn("part2", split(col("testcolumn"), ":|:|:").getItem(3))
.withColumn("part3", split(col("testcolumn"), ":|:|:").getItem(6))
```

part1 and part2 work correctly.
part3 only has 2 characters and rest of the string is truncated.

part3:

```
P
```

I want to get the entire part3 string.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there – just need to escape `|` within your delimiter, as follows:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "TEST:|:|:51:|:|:PHT054008056"),
  (2, "TEST:|:|:52:|:|:PHT053007057")
).toDF("id", "testcolumn")

df.withColumn("part3", split($"testcolumn", ":\\|:\\|:").getItem(2)).show
// +---+--------------------+------------+
// | id|          testcolumn|       part3|
// +---+--------------------+------------+
// |  1|TEST:|:|:51:|:|:P...|PHT054008056|
// |  2|TEST:|:|:52:|:|:P...|PHT053007057|
// +---+--------------------+------------+
```

[UPDATE]

You could also use triple quotes for the delimiter, in which case you still have to escape `|` to indicate it's a literal pipe (not `or` in Regex):

```
df.withColumn("part3", split($"testcolumn", """:\|:\|:""").getItem(2)).show
```

Note that with triple quotes, you need only a single escape character `\`, whereas without the triple quotes the escape character itself needs to be escaped (hence `\\`).